# enum in Rails 5 for polymorphic associations and overriding default behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

1) Can `enum` be used for polymorphic associations well?

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum my_status: [:a, :b, :c, :d]
end


class MyModel2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum my_status: [:aa, :bb, :cc, :dd]
end
```

Any downsides?

2) Can I override getter or setter for enum and how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `MyModel` and `MyModel2` are two possible types of a polymorphic association.

1. Having the same attribute name with different behavior is what polymorphism is good at, I don't see any reason not to use it for this.
2. Enum attributes can have their getters and setters overwritten just like any attribute.

For example:

```
# Return the status as uppercase
def my_status
  super.upcase
end

# Save status as lowercase
def my_status=(new_status)
  super(new_status.downcase)
end
```

The special methods added by the enum macro can be overridden in the same way.